# Is this any kind of algebraical property?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I've consulted everywhere but I can't explain myself how come $\displaystyle \int \frac{u-1-1}{(u-1)^2} du $, turns into $\displaystyle \int \bigg(\frac{1}{(u-1)} - \frac{1}{(u-1)^2}\bigg) du $, I found this step in a differential equation from Denis Zill Book, thanks in advance

Comment: just split the fraction in the original integral.

Comment: Apply distributed property

Comment: You can simplify because {1} is a set with null measure

Comment: should I move (u-1)^2 to the numerator?

Comment: It's just partial fractions, a normal integration technique.

Comment: thanks to everyone, now I get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{(u-1)-1}{(u-1)^2} = \frac{u-1}{(u-1)^2} - \frac 1 {(u-1)^2} = \frac 1 {u-1} - \frac 1 {(u-1)^2}
$$

Comment: God, I'm such a blind dude, sorry about that question man!!!